# Importar archivos externos con consulta SQL en Python y Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Vengo de PHP y estoy aprendiendo python y queria saber si es posible hacer en python un archivo que sea mi archivo principal (con una ventana creada con tkinter) y tener archivos externos (ya he importado modulos) que realicen consulta en una base de datos y muestren los registros y cargarlo en la ventana principal creada con tkinter?
La otra forma que se me ocurre es hacerlo con una ventana modal, pero estoy intentando hacer la primera opcion. Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.